# Why can't a const mutable lambda with an auto& parameter be invoked?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, type-traits, static-assert

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    auto f1 = [](auto&) mutable {};
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f1), int&>); // ok

    auto const f2 = [](auto&) {};
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f2), int&>); // ok

    auto const f3 = [](auto&) mutable {};
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f3), int&>); // failed
}
```

See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/69eWPe5bG)

**Why can't a const mutable lambda take a reference argument?**

Comment: @DavisHerring If the parameter is `int&` then the program compiles. If the parameter is `void` then the program compiles. Thus, it has something with the argument.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two interesting things here.

First, a lambda's call operator (template) is `const` by default. If you provide `mutable`, then it is not `const`. The effect of `mutable` on a lambda is *solely* the opposite of the effect of trailing `const` in normal member functions (it does not affect lambda capture, etc.)

So if you look at this:

```cpp
auto const f3 = [](auto&) mutable {};
static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f3), int&>); // failed
```

This is a `const` object, whose call operator template (because it's a generic lambda) is non-`const`. So you can't invoke it, for the same reason you can't invoke a non-`const` member function on a `const` object in any other context. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70309342/2069064).

Second, it has been pointed out that, nevertheless, this works:

```cpp
auto const f4 = [](int&) mutable {}; // changed auto& to int&
static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f4), int&>); // now ok
```

This is *not* a compiler bug. *Nor* does it mean that what I just said was wrong. `f4` *still* has a *non-const* call operator. Which you cannot invoke, because `f4` is a const object.

However.

There's one other interesting aspect of lambdas that have no capture: they have a conversion function to a function pointer type. That is, we usually think about the lambda `f4` as looking like this:

```cpp
struct __unique_f4 {
    auto operator()(int&) /* not const */ { }
};
```

And, if that were the whole story, `const __unique_f4` is indeed not invocable with `int&`. But it *actually* looks like this:

```cpp
struct __unique_f4 {
    auto operator()(int&) /* not const */ { }

    // conversion function to the appropriate function
    // pointer type
    operator void(*)(int&)() const { /* ... */ }
};
```

And there is this rule we have where when you invoke an object, like `f(x)`, you not only consider `f`'s call operators -- those members named `operator()` -- but you also consider any of `f`'s [surrogate call functions](https://eel.is/c++draft/over#def:surrogate_call_function) -- are there any function pointers that you can convert `f` to, to then invoke.

In this case, you can! You can convert `f4` to a `void(*)(int&)` and that function pointer is invocable with `int&`.

But that still means that `f4`'s call operator is not const, because you declared it mutable. And it doesn't say anything about whether you can have `mutable` lambdas take reference parameters.

Comment: It looks like there is no conversion function to function pointer available, if `auto operator()(auto&)`?

Comment: @S.M. There are still conversion function operators, it's just that it looks like (for `f3` anyway): `template <typename T> operator void(*)(T&) const`. But conversion function _templates_ aren't part of the "surrogate call function" rule, just conversion functions - you can use them in other contexts though: `auto const f3 = [](auto&) mutable {}; void(*p)(int&) = f3; // ok`

Answer (score 13):

You get an error for this for the very same reason:

```
struct foo {
    void operator()(){}
};

int main() {
    const foo f;
    f();
}
```

The error is:

```
<source>:7:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const foo'
    f();
    ^
<source>:2:10: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const foo', but method is not marked const
    void operator()(){}
         ^
```

Because you cannot call a non-const method on a const instance. Lambdas got the default constness right, so without `mutable` the `operator()` is `const`. With `mutable` the `operator()` is a non-const method that you cannot call on a `const f3;`

Comment: If this is the reason, why does changing `f3` to from `[](auto&) mutable {}` to `[](int&) mutable {}` make the program valid?

Comment: @S.M. No, `operator()` is definitely not `const` with a `mutable` lambda. http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-5.sentence-1

Comment: @S.M. this error say something else https://godbolt.org/z/W6TnMbnYx. Of course I might be wrong though

Comment: @Brian looks like a bug to me

Comment: @Brian Want to ask that as a question? The answer is wonderful :-)

Comment: @S.M. mutable doesn't make lambda members mutable. It makes lambda members non-const.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It is not a bug.

Comment: @Barry then I am looking forward to the explaination ;). Going to delete this answer, as the quesiton is just about that difference.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Why? Your answer is correct.

Comment: @Barry oh right, the thingy about `int&` is only in comments

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number How you explain the success https://godbolt.org/z/MbcW5MT5M?

Comment: @S.M. i cant ;). Lets open another question about that. I'd love to see the answer

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Added an answer vvv

Comment: @Barry [Asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70309497/11082165), though now rightly closed as a dupe to this one thanks to your excellent answer.