# Why are const mutable generic lambdas not invocable

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer

Consider the following four lambdas:

```
#include <type_traits>

const auto f1 = [](auto) mutable {};  // const, mutable, generic
const auto f2 = [](auto) {};          // const,          generic
const auto f3 = [](int)  mutable {};  // const, mutable
auto f4 = [](auto) mutable {};        //        mutable, generic

static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f1), int>); // failed
static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f2), int>); // not mutable, okay
static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f3), int>); // not generic, okay
static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f4), int>); // not const, okay

int main() {}
```

See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EM9c6vood)

Why aren't const, mutable, generic lambdas invocable, when any pairing of const, mutable or generic *does* produce an invocable lambda?

Comment: The plot thickens.  `(static_cast<void(*)(int)>(f1))(1);` works.